# Вывод текста в консоль браузера

Tags: gwt, java

Надо сделать отладочный вывод в консоль браузера. Чтобы это работало не только в `HostedMode`, но и в `WebMode`. Как это сделать? Вроде пишут, что метод `GWT.log(text)` работает только в `HostedMode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классический способ - использование [**gwt-log.**](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) В зависимости от выбранного хендлера, вы можете логировать данные куда угодно *(лично я предпочитаю)* `Firebug`, а логирование вообще контролируется параметром `log_level`.

*[**Здесь**](http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.demo.LogDemo/LogDemo.html) можно найти демонстрацию, понятно, что без разницы, установлен Hosted Mode или Web Mode.*

---

**P.S.** Вопрос к тем, кто хорошо разбирается - как в `GWT` совершается оптимизация логгинга при `log_level = off`? Т.е, насколько серьезно реализован статический анализ кода в плане `dead code elimination` и можно ли в продакшене безболезненно расчитывать на эти оптимизации?